# CSS @keyframe animation flickers on hover

Tags: css, hover, css-animations, flicker, keyframe

Looking for help! I'm having a flickering issue with the keyframe animation I made for the hover state. I'm using Squarespace and adding custom code to the site. Designer by trade so forgive my code, I'm stuck.

View site here: https://dingbat.co/new-fonts

[Flicker Issue on Hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNky2.gif)

```css
img {
  max-width:100%;
}

img:hover{
  opacity: 1 !important;
  animation: bruxism 1s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: steps(100);
}
@keyframes bruxism{
    0%   { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b57d4d3cc5898fb517d/1589152599764/Brux7.png'); } 
    8%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b54655c7270e62be6c0/1589152597813/Brux6.png'); }
   16%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b51c673416ea88b386c/1589152593259/Brux5.png');}
   24%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b4d2ffa577e027396e2/1589152589870/Brux4.png'); }
   32%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b4a0f826758a3cff34f/1589152586700/Brux3.png'); }
   40%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b47b2acbe6aa4f0715f/1589152583216/Brux2.png'); }
   48%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b4440f56e45feecd847/1589152580316/Brux1.png'); }
   50%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b4440f56e45feecd847/1589152580316/Brux1.png'); }
   58%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b47b2acbe6aa4f0715f/1589152583216/Brux2.png'); }
   66%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b4a0f826758a3cff34f/1589152586700/Brux3.png'); }
   74%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b4d2ffa577e027396e2/1589152589870/Brux4.png'); }
   82%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b51c673416ea88b386c/1589152593259/Brux5.png'); }
   90%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b54655c7270e62be6c0/1589152597813/Brux6.png'); }
   98%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b57d4d3cc5898fb517d/1589152599764/Brux7.png'); }
  100%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b57d4d3cc5898fb517d/1589152599764/Brux7.png'); }
}

body {
  background:#000;
}
```

```html
<img src='https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b57d4d3cc5898fb517d/1589152599764/Brux7.png' >
```

Comment: all the image will be loaded on the hover. You need to load them on page load to avoid this

Comment: There are lots of images, and they all look quite large, based on the few I've loaded. It takes the browser time to load these on-demand. I'd try doing it without using images if possible, you (and the user loading the page) will use a lot of bandwidth otherwise - bad for accessibility, load time, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are intrested you can approximate this using only CSS with text-stroke. You simply need to update with the correct font-family:

```css
body {
  background:#000
}

.logo {
   font-family:monospace;
   text-transform:uppercase;
   font-size:60px;
   color:#fff;
   animation: bruxism 1s infinite steps(6);
}

@keyframes bruxism{
   0% {
     -webkit-text-stroke:1px #fff;
             text-stroke:1px #fff;
  }
  20% {
     -webkit-text-stroke:2px #fff;
             text-stroke:2px #fff;
  }
  40% {
     -webkit-text-stroke:3px #fff;
             text-stroke:3px #fff;
  }
  60% {
     -webkit-text-stroke:4px #fff;
             text-stroke:4px #fff;
  }
  80% {
     -webkit-text-stroke:5px #fff;
             text-stroke:5px #fff;
  }
  100% {
     -webkit-text-stroke:6px #fff;
             text-stroke:6px #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">bruxism</div>
```

Or make sure to load all your images initially to make them ready on hover and avoid the flicker:

I considered an empty pseudo element where I apply all the images as background to force the browser to fetch them

```css
html:before {
  content:"";  background:url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b57d4d3cc5898fb517d/1589152599764/Brux7.png'), url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b54655c7270e62be6c0/1589152597813/Brux6.png'), url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b51c673416ea88b386c/1589152593259/Brux5.png'), url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b4d2ffa577e027396e2/1589152589870/Brux4.png'), url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b4a0f826758a3cff34f/1589152586700/Brux3.png'), url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b47b2acbe6aa4f0715f/1589152583216/Brux2.png'), url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b4440f56e45feecd847/1589152580316/Brux1.png'), url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b4440f56e45feecd847/1589152580316/Brux1.png'), url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b47b2acbe6aa4f0715f/1589152583216/Brux2.png'), url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b4a0f826758a3cff34f/1589152586700/Brux3.png'), url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b4d2ffa577e027396e2/1589152589870/Brux4.png'), url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b51c673416ea88b386c/1589152593259/Brux5.png'), url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b54655c7270e62be6c0/1589152597813/Brux6.png'), url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b57d4d3cc5898fb517d/1589152599764/Brux7.png'), url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b57d4d3cc5898fb517d/1589152599764/Brux7.png'); 
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
}
img:hover{
  opacity: 1 !important;
  animation: bruxism 1s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: steps(100);
}
@keyframes bruxism{
    0%   { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b57d4d3cc5898fb517d/1589152599764/Brux7.png'); } 
    8%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b54655c7270e62be6c0/1589152597813/Brux6.png'); }
   16%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b51c673416ea88b386c/1589152593259/Brux5.png');}
   24%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b4d2ffa577e027396e2/1589152589870/Brux4.png'); }
   32%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b4a0f826758a3cff34f/1589152586700/Brux3.png'); }
   40%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b47b2acbe6aa4f0715f/1589152583216/Brux2.png'); }
   48%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b4440f56e45feecd847/1589152580316/Brux1.png'); }
   50%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b4440f56e45feecd847/1589152580316/Brux1.png'); }
   58%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b47b2acbe6aa4f0715f/1589152583216/Brux2.png'); }
   66%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b4a0f826758a3cff34f/1589152586700/Brux3.png'); }
   74%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b4d2ffa577e027396e2/1589152589870/Brux4.png'); }
   82%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b51c673416ea88b386c/1589152593259/Brux5.png'); }
   90%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b54655c7270e62be6c0/1589152597813/Brux6.png'); }
   98%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b57d4d3cc5898fb517d/1589152599764/Brux7.png'); }
  100%  { content: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b57d4d3cc5898fb517d/1589152599764/Brux7.png'); }
}

body {
  background:#000;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54dfad58e4b0d9caed78a9a9/t/5eb88b57d4d3cc5898fb517d/1589152599764/Brux7.png" >
```