# Load certain images before sending any other requests to the server

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I have a basic Node js express web application with webix UI on the front-end.

There are a lot of components/tables with a lot of data that needs to be populated in these tables.

I have a loading screen with some background-images changing background image URL every 3 secs until the loading of all the data is complete.

The problem with the loading screen is that the images are not the first thing that get downloaded by the browser. The tables sometimes populate even before the images get downloaded and it beats the whole purpose of having the loading screen.

I was wondering if there was a way I can load these images first thing when the application is opened in the browser.

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<body>
        <div id="container-id" class="container">
            <div id="text-id" class="text">Loading...</div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes changeBg
    {
        0%  {background-image: url("/resources/images/one.jpg");}
        25%   {background-image: url("/resources/images/two.jpg");}
        50%   {background-image: url("/resources/images/three.jpg");}
        75%  {background-image: url("/resources/images/four.jpg");}
        100%  {background-image: url("/resources/images/five.jpg");}
    }
    .container {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background-image: url("/resources/images/one.jpg");
      -webkit-animation: changeBg 15s infinite;
      background-size: 100%;
      background-position: center;
    }
```

Based on this similar question: [load specific image before anything else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511352/load-specific-image-before-anything-else)

I tried loading the images using the javascript as first few lines in the index page as follows:

```
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (new Image()).src= window.location.href + "resources/images/one.jpg";
            (new Image()).src= window.location.href + "resources/images/two.jpg";
            (new Image()).src= window.location.href + "resources/images/three.jpg";
            (new Image()).src= window.location.href + "resources/images/four.jpg";
            (new Image()).src= window.location.href + "resources/images/five.jpg";
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="webix.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
</head>
```

But still, the other requests get served way before the images.

Comment: can you try implementing it with `promises` ?

Comment: Can't use ```Promises```? e.g: psudo code: ```ImagePromise.All(fetchImages).then(loadDOM)``` ?

Comment: if you are using node as a server, try to react for frontend. React make this thing simpler. :)

Comment: @KarlL You mean load the images in a Promise and then load rest of the CSS and JS files in the "then" piece?  How would the <link> assests be recognized in the then part- Am I getting something wrong here? Is there a way you can post a JSFiddle or a sample snippet in the answer

Comment: @cybercoder I haven't tried that but how would I even declare rest of the assets in the "then" part like Javascript wont recognize the <link> tags - Am I getting something wrong here? Is there a way you can post a JSFiddle or a sample snippet in the answer

Comment: @NickDiv yup, see if that works for you.

Comment: @Prabeshgauli Not sure I understand - Is there a link or article you can direct me to.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62751505/10002142 
https://www.javascriptstuff.com/detect-image-load/

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61762176/8620333 (maybe if it's done with CSS it's faster)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I tried that as well but it still seems like the data requests are fired before the image requests. Somehow I think they are marked lower in priority by the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually scripts are loaded by order they are placed in the `head`. Browser won't wait for event to being raised then go for other scripts to load (It doesn't make sense). So your script is loaded completely but it's `event` for image loading are not raised.

So we have to `await` until all images are loaded `then` load scripts.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadImageAsync(url) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            let img = new Image();
            img.src = url;
            img.addEventListener('load', e => resolve(img));
        });
    };

    async function loadImages() {
        var im1 = loadImageAsync("imageUrlOne");
        var im2 = loadImageAsync("imageUrlTwo");

        var image1 = await im1;
        console.log(`image one loaded..., url:${image1.src}`)
        var image2 = await im2
        console.log(`image two loaded..., url:${image2.src}`)
    }

    function loadScript(url) {
        var script = document.createElement("script")
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = url;
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    }

    loadImages().then(() => {
        console.log("loading scripts...");
        loadScript("script 1 url here");
        loadScript("script 2 url here");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Tried that, didn't help. The script to load images is the first thing on the page. The rest of the assets are declared after the script that I have posted in the Question.

Comment: This looks like something that could work but I have some variables that are injected in my script(.dust) that dictate the authorization of the user - by setting the loading of the rest of the scripts in "then" logic I wont be able to pass that authorization. Having said that, I did not mention this scenario in my question. You did answer what I had asked for and I really appreciate the help.

Comment: After tweaking my dust file for a bit and using some workarounds I got this to work. Appreciate the effort. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use react js for such things, Reactjs makes lots of thing like this easy.
To know more about react .

> Visit: https://reactjs.org/

```
import React from "react";

class ImageWithStatusText extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { imageStatus: "loading" };
  }

  handleImageLoaded() {
    this.setState({ imageStatus: "loaded" });
  }

  handleImageErrored() {
    this.setState({ imageStatus: "failed to load" });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <img
          src={this.props.imageUrl}
          onLoad={this.handleImageLoaded.bind(this)}
          onError={this.handleImageErrored.bind(this)}
        />
        {this.state.imageStatus}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default ImageWithStatusText;
```

Comment: I cannot change the tech stack right now but maybe for a different application.