# Preload images and use them as backgound of div element

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, preload

I am running a very simple slide show that changes the background of a div after some time. The problem is that the images are loaded too slow and a blank screen appears between image changes. Now I want to preload the images and I found [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373142/preloading-css-images), but they did not work, and:

```
var myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = 'picture.jpg';
```

Can I somehow use this `myImage` as background-image of a div? Or do you know any other methods for preloading background-images?

Using `:after` pseudo-elements did not work.

Comment: maybe try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61762176/8620333

Comment: Please provide the exact code you tried, or at least a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using blobs and `URL.createObjectURL()`.

```js
let imgUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/VG2UvcY.jpg";

const preloadBtn = document.getElementById("preload-btn"),
      showBtn = document.getElementById("show-btn");


preloadBtn.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  imgUrl = URL.createObjectURL(
    await (await fetch(imgUrl)).blob()
  );
  preloadBtn.disabled = true;
});

showBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url("${imgUrl}")`
});
```

```css
body {
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<button id="preload-btn">Preload big image</button>
<button id="show-btn">Show big image</button>
```